# Quickblox on IE-8/IE-9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, quickblox

Does quickblox's javascript library works on IE8/IE9?

I am getting "No Transport" error while creating the session. As per few suggestions on SO, I am using following scripts

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ajaxtransport-xdomainrequest/1.0.2/jquery.xdomainrequest.min.js"></script>
```

But I am not having any luck.

The other option I tried was, setting following property:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

This gives me "Access Denied" error.

I would appreciate any help or pointers to get this right on IE.

Comment: The IE10+ browser support is mainly due to chat. If you want to just make REST API calls, it should work... can you give a bit more info about this "Access Denied" error? This seems like an AJAX issue rather than a Quickblox issue - but you could help to improve the compatibility of the library :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using Quickblox's javascript SDK and as per documentation:

http://quickblox.com/developers/Javascript#Browsers_support

It only supports IE10+.